# Failover cluster SQL server 2016: 'the remote computer refused the connection'

Tags: failovercluster, sql-server-2016, connection-refused

**BACKGROUND**

We have a new SQL server 2016 failover cluster (without Always On) (clu1) with 2 nodes (sql1-2) and 4 roles/instances (app1-4)

Connections from de nodes to the cluster instances work fine

*SSMS: clu1-app1\app1*

**THE ISSUE**

However, we can't connect to the instances from any other machine:

*SSMS: clu1-app1\app1*

```
'A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)

The network path was not found'
```

[Error screenshot 01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ye4c.png)

*SSMS: clu1-app1\app1,1433*

```
'A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The remote computer refused the network connection.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1225)

The remote computer refused the network connection'
```

[Error screenshot 02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlB5w.png)

Our network engineer let us know that the connections pass the firewall, but the cluster does not respond to connections outside the VLAN.

**THE SETTINGS**

The settings are the same on the nodes

[Allow remote connections to the server is checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zi3MM.png)

[Software firewall is off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvWIi.png)

[SQL Server Network Configuration settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3Mrt.png)

I've ran 'Test-DbaConnection' from [dbatools](https://dbatools.io), but I'm none the wiser...

**THE QUESTION**

Are there any more settings I need to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We got it working by adding a Dynamic Port in the 'IPAll' section of the TCP/IP Properties